# How do I find a specific fragment in a list of fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, arraylist

I have a list of `fragments` and want to find a specific one based on the `fragment type` passed in as an argument. Sort of like this:

```
private fun findFragment(findFragment: Fragment): Fragment {
    fragments.forEach {
        if (it is findFragment) {
            return it
        }
    }
}

findFragment(MyFragment)
```

I don't want to send an instance but rather the type, and if that type exists in the list, the instance should be returned. I get an error on `if (it is findFragment)` saying unresolved reference findMyFragment.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: You can try to use that `type` or class name and set that as a tag for the fragment. And then you can just search fragment by tag. Either in your list or using `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)`

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your parameter is not a `class` but only a **variable**. You can not use `instanceof` or in this case `is` to another variable.

The closest solution that is possible in this case is to use the name of your fragment. Something like this:

```
    private fun findFragment(findFragment: String): Fragment? {
        val fragments = listOf<Fragment>()
        fragments.forEach {
            if (it.javaClass.simpleName == findFragment) {
                return it
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

Then you can call this method :

```
findFragment(MyFragment::class.java.simpleName)
```